# How to load maps only once the permission is granted

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am developing one classified portal their user can post their ads and I used Google geolocation feature to get the user's current location coordinates form the browser.

The browser asking to grant permission, But I want to only display the map if only the permission is granted. If not I have to put some default coordinates for the location.

Here is my current code :

```
  <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
      // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
      // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
      // locate you.
      var map, infoWindow;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 13
        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
            document.cookie = "myJavascriptVar=12345";


        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var my_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       position: pos,
                       map: map,
                       "icon": 'map.png',
                       draggable: true,
                   });

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            //infoWindow.setContent('You are here');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }

      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
```

How I can check if browser permission is granted or not ?

Why it asking every time I refresh the page ?

Comment: *I want to only display the map if only the permission is granted. If not I have to put some default coordinates for the location.* - That is **contradictory**. You want to load it or not? Possibly you want to do it like it is explained in many Q/A here. Load the map with default coords, then change to the user position, if you get it, ie. if it was allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you want to display a map or not, so I'll show you code samples of how you can do either of these.

A) If you want to first show a map at the default coordinates while you ask the user for location permission, and keep the default map if the user blocks permission.

```
var map, infoWindow;
var defaultPos = { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 };

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: defaultPos,
    zoom: 13
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  document.cookie = "myJavascriptVar=12345";

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      var my_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
      });

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('You are here');
      infoWindow.open(map, my_marker);
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      // user didn't grant permission so keep using default coordinates
    });
  }
}
```

B) If you don't want to show a map at first while asking the user for location permission, and then show a map with default coordinates if the user blocks permission.

```
var map, infoWindow;
var defaultPos = { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 };

function initMap() {

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  document.cookie = "myJavascriptVar=12345";

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: pos,
        zoom: 13
      });

      var my_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
      });

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('You are here');
      infoWindow.open(map, my_marker);
    }, function() {
      // user didn't grant permission so display a map with default coordinates
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: defaultPos,
        zoom: 13
      });
    });
  }
}
```

C) If you only want to show a map with the user's location if the user grants location permission, without any default coordinates fallback.

```
var map, infoWindow;

function initMap() {

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  document.cookie = "myJavascriptVar=12345";

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: pos,
        zoom: 13
      });

      var my_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
      });

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('You are here');
      infoWindow.open(map, my_marker);
    }, function() {
      // user didn't grant permission so display nothing
    });
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!